# Sprite kit deforming textures?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am trying to animate a stickman walking. However, when I animate its texture atlas, the second image deforms and is stretched along the x-axis. Here's the code for setting up the scene:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* GROUND */

        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:1 alpha:1.0];

        CGFloat groundHeight = (size.height / 2) - 50;

        CGSize groundSize = CGSizeMake(size.width, groundHeight);

        SKSpriteNode *ground = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] size:groundSize];

        ground.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), (groundHeight / 2));

        [self addChild:ground];

        /* STICKMAN */

        SKTextureAtlas *stickmanTextureAtlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"Stickman"];

        stickmanFrames = @[[stickmanTextureAtlas textureNamed:@"stickman1"],
                           [stickmanTextureAtlas textureNamed:@"stickman2"]];

        stickmanSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:stickmanFrames[0]];

        CGPoint stickmanPosition = CGPointMake(200, 100);
        stickmanSprite.position = stickmanPosition;

        [self addChild:stickmanSprite];

        [stickmanSprite runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:
                         [SKAction animateWithTextures:stickmanFrames
                                       timePerFrame:0.5f
                                             resize:NO
                                            restore:YES]] withKey:@"walkingInPlaceStickman"];

    }
    return self;
}
```

Why is this happening? Even without scaling the image using its CGSize this still happens. The images' actual sizes in pixels are the same.

Comment: try resize:YES in animate action

Comment: It works! But how do I scale a sprite? I mean if I want to make it fit on the screen, because mine's too large. Or do I just change the PNG's size (in pixels)?

Comment: I looked it up... I have to use the xScale and yScale properties. Now it works perfectly. Write an answer for the question so that I can give you credit for it (give it a tick)!